# What would be an API end point to retrieve all customer's review of a product and all reviews of a specific customer

Tags: laravel, rest

My line o thinking is this:

```
get evaluations //would retrieve all evaluations of the system. (in practice  never used).

post evaluations create a new evaluation
```

Following the Rest pattern

```
get evaluations/1 //details of the evaluation with id "1"
```

But I was using

```
get evaluation/{product_id}
```

To retrieve all evaluations of a product.

For what I know of Rest design this is not good. It would be something like this:

evaluations?product_id=5

Now, what it would be an endpoint to retrieve all reviews of a specific client? I am using Auth 2.0.

I am really confused.

Is it possible to shove it all in one controller?

In summary, I would like to know if the endpoint evaluations?product_id=9 is suitable to retrieve all evaluations of a product. And what would be and endpoint to retrieve all evaluations of a client that has a token.

Comment: With laravel there’s no need for an actual query parameter, so your request url would look like “api/evaluations/1”. You could, to make it more intuitive, check if the parameter is set, and if not return all evaluations. So in your routes file you set the route parameter to optional, like evaluation/{product_id?}. TLDR; api/get/evaluations/{param?} is a clean enough route, as long is it’s consistent with your other routes.

Comment: To retrieve all evaluations of a product - according to REST it should be products/{product_id}/evaluations. According to REST your path should determine a resource. Technically, query parameters are not part of the REST architecture(https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/01/understanding-using-rest-api/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many approachs here:

- Separate Endpoints:
  Suche as:

get /users/{user_id}/evaluations

get /products/{product_ID}/evaluations

get /evaluations/{evaluation_id}

- single endpoint

get /evaluations/{type}/{id}

And in your controller implement a logic to retrieve evaluations according to the type (user, product,...) and the id of the selected type.

Personally, I prefer the first one.